# calling SAS command statements from R

Tags: r, sas

I was thinking of running SAS commands in R since the SAS version I have is incompatible with my windows. The windows I had was windows 7 and decided to upgrade to 8.1,
Is it possible?

Comment: So you want to run SAS commands in R? You know they are completely different programs, right? R can't run SAS scripts or python scripts or java programs or COBOL programs. It pretty much just runs R code. I'm confused as to exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: recommendation: just start using R.

Comment: @Frank But those interact with the underlying programs. If you don't even have SAS installed, you can't interact with it.

Comment: See this posting on the [R help list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Re-Executing-SAS-Codes-in-R-td4648739.html). I think it answer's your question, or at the very least will help you to clarify your question.

Comment: You can download SAS UE for free from SAS website. If you have/had a legitimate license you can contact your SAS rep for a newer version that is Windows 8 compatible.

Comment: @Reeza Can you use that with R?  I know you can't go the other way, and since it's on a VM, I wonder if R could see the UE instance.

Comment: @joe Doubt it, but question appears to be I've lost access to SAS, how can I use R to make that up?

Answer (score 3):

No. In your situation it isn't possible.  If you had a working installation of SAS you might be able to connect them through `system` calls but if SAS isn't working then you can't just run SAS code from within R.

You'll either need to get SAS working on your computer or just run R code.

Comment: what about the R markdown in rstudio?

Comment: give me the systems call steps

Comment: Is SAS working on your system? If not then it doesn't matter.